# Constant kernel panics on MacBook Pro 16 (2019) while asleep - GPU?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, kernel-panic

For months I'm trying to find a reason why my MBP16 randomly crashes while in sleep mode. The trace is very similar every time:

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff800e814e67): "IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00::setPowerState(0xffffff805b9e6a20 : 0xffffff7f8f0c2234, 3 -> 2) timed out after 101145 ms"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.141.1/iokit/Kernel/IOServicePM.cpp:5296
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa3f5733b40 : 0xffffff800e11a65d 
0xffffffa3f5733b90 : 0xffffff800e254a75 
0xffffffa3f5733bd0 : 0xffffff800e2465fe 
0xffffffa3f5733c20 : 0xffffff800e0c0a40 
0xffffffa3f5733c40 : 0xffffff800e119d27 
0xffffffa3f5733d40 : 0xffffff800e11a117 
0xffffffa3f5733d90 : 0xffffff800e8c1abc 
0xffffffa3f5733e00 : 0xffffff800e814e67 
0xffffffa3f5733e50 : 0xffffff800e814749 
0xffffffa3f5733e60 : 0xffffff800e82bcde 
0xffffffa3f5733ea0 : 0xffffff800e8134f8 
0xffffffa3f5733ec0 : 0xffffff800e15c605 
0xffffffa3f5733f40 : 0xffffff800e15c131 
0xffffffa3f5733fa0 : 0xffffff800e0c013e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19G2021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Jun 18 20:49:00 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D3A0F3D-D908-397B-BD16-8F48C0823A2E
Kernel slide:     0x000000000de00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800e000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800df00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 65167739947363
last loaded kext at 62443535556083: >!AXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7f91d4d000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 62624364153903: >!AXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7f91d4d000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver   3.7.0
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.4
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.1.0
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.2.6
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.7
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.7
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!AMuxControl2  5.2.6
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.7
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.429
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
@filesystems.ntfs   3.14.3
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.1.0
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.1.0
>!UAudio    323.4
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f7
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    3.1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@kext.triggers  1.0
>Core!S 551
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter  2.5.4
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
>!ASSE  1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Did anyone maybe found any solution for this issue?

Comment: Is there anything plugged into this Mac while it is sleeping? *IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00::setPowerState(0xffffff805b9e6a20* This might indicate an issue with an external device. Not sure as I may be reading it wrong but worth a try...

Comment: You've updated to 10.15.6 supplemental update?

Comment: Yes, I read that 10.15.6 supposedly fixed this (https://mrmacintosh.com/10-15-4-update-wake-from-sleep-kernel-panic-in-16-mbpro-2019/) but this kp actually comes from 10.15.6, so I guess it's not fixed.

Comment: @SteveChambers: The issue seems to be more pronounced with 3 screens connected (as here), but also happens with just a charger.